# boolean type serialization and deserialization unit test failed

Tags: java, serialization, junit, boolean

After running a Junit test for boolean type serialization, it is always failed with `true` value my serialize method as follows

```
public static void serializeBoolean(boolean objectToSerialize, OutputStream outputStream) {
   byte[] bytesArr = new byte[1];
   ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesArr).put((byte) (objectToSerialize ? 1 : 0));
   try {
   outputStream.write(bytesArr);
   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

And my deserialize method as follows

```
public static boolean deserializeBoolean(InputStream inputStream) {
   byte[] databytesArr = new byte[1];
   if (ByteBuffer.wrap(databytesArr).get() == 1) {
   return true;
   }
   else {
   return false;
   }
}
```

Finally, I wrote a unit test as follows

```
public class BooleanSerializerTest {

  private InputStream iStream;
  private ByteArrayOutputStream oStream;

@Before
public void init() {
  oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 }

  boolean serialzeAndDeserializeObject(boolean booleanValue) {
  OutputStreamUtil.serializeBoolean(booleanValue, oStream);
  iStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oStream.toByteArray());
  return InputStreamUtil.deserializeBoolean(iStream);
}

@Test
public void equalToTrue() {
  boolean booleanValue = true;
  boolean deserializedBooleanValue = 
  serialzeAndDeserializeObject(booleanValue);
  assertThat(deserializedBooleanValue).isEqualTo(booleanValue);
}

@Test
public void equalToFalse() {
  boolean booleanValue = false;
  boolean deserializedBooleanValue = 
  serialzeAndDeserializeObject(booleanValue);
  assertThat(deserializedBooleanValue).isEqualTo(booleanValue);
  }
}
```

`equalToFalse()` test was succeed but `equalToTrue()` is always fail

what was wrong? and how to fix it?

Comment: The method `deserializeBoolean(InputStream inputStream)` doesn't use its parameter `inputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add `inputStream.read(databytesArr);` in the method `deserializeBoolean` as follow:

```
    public static boolean deserializeBoolean(InputStream inputStream) {
        byte[] databytesArr = new byte[1];
        try {
            inputStream.read(databytesArr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (ByteBuffer.wrap(databytesArr).get() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the input parameter `inputStream` isn't used you get always the same result update the `deserializeBoolean` method as follows:

```
public static boolean deserializeBoolean(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] databytesArr = new byte[1];
    inputStream.read(databytesArr);
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(databytesArr).get() == 1;
}
```

Thereafter the tests will succeed.